# error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure occured

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl

When I use a curl request, there appears an error.
I already tried another article answer, but didn't worked.

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'SSLv3');` // add this, not worked

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');` // add this, not worked
```

My server version:

- PHP Version 5.2.17
- OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
- libcurl/7.15.5

Code:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $_headers );
$result = curl_exec( $curl );
```

> error:  error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: you sure you need to use `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` at all?

Comment: if not use, `error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure` this error appeared  @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure

Comment: thank you, @MarcinOrlowski  :) I'll try upgrade version.

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 or above, and use [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).